# Avoid chaining critical requests issue for loading CSS file [PageSpeed Insights]

Tags: css, pagespeed, google-pagespeed, pagespeed-insights

I want to know how I can remove or reduce the time that my css takes to load. PageSpeed Insights suggests that I should 'Avoid chaining critical requests'. It is supposed to add about 170ms give or take to the loading time.

I have tried loading deferred/async but it just results in massive layout shifts. The file size is about 8KiB.

Are there any simple and modern solutions to load it before HTML but not block the loading process?

Answer (score 0):

You could split the CSS. Have layout critical CSS either inlined or sync loaded, and the rest you can async load.